# How can i create background canvas animated effect?

Tags: javascript, canvas, background, onmouseover, animated

I found one here:
http://tympanus.net/Development/AnimatedHeaderBackgrounds/
but need more like what i am looking for.

Is this possible to create with HTML5 Canvas?

Comment: How can i create background effect like this? deutser dot com ?

Can anyone help and tell me if i can find some existing effects that i can use in my website like these or if i can create one like this ?

Comment: deutser dot com background effect is what i am looking for to duplicate please

Comment: Please be more specific in your question.  You don't include any information about what you've tried, or specific things that you need help with.

Comment: Actually i want to create background effect like this website has:
http://goo.gl/DBIS09

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. All you need to do is have an algorithm that you use for those particles. I personally would never do something like this because they are only just one little effect on a webpage, to me they just aren't worth it.

---

But all you have to do is to figure out some particle algorithm. Here's a really cool html5 canvas particles demo: http://cssdeck.com/labs/html5-canvas-particles-web-matrix;

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but what i am looking for is how to create a logo with particles and then move then moved on mouse over.

Comment: Then just use an event listener to change the positions.                                                      `document.addEventListener("mousemove", function() {                                             // code you do to move particles when mouse moved                                      });`